# Slot, stop method called multiple times

Tags: android, logic, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a slot machine code where it rolls through random fruits with a maxCount for each slot. Once the maxCount is reached that slot will stop. However, sometimes the slot, stop method is called more than once. Any ideas?

**TimerTask**

```
 TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                count++;
                if (!slotOneFinished){
                    animate(randomSwitchCount(), slotOne, count);
                }
                if (!slotTwoFinished) {
                    animate(randomSwitchCount(), slotTwo,count);
                }
                if (!slotThreeFinished) {
                    animate(randomSwitchCount(), slotThree,count);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**Stop function**

```
public void stop(ImageSwitcher slot){
    if (slot.equals(slotOne)){
        slotOneFinished=true;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (slot.equals(slotTwo)){
        slotTwoFinished=true;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (slot.equals(slotThree)){
        slotThreeFinished=true;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (slotOneFinished&&slotTwoFinished&&slotThreeFinished){
        executor.shutdown();
        executor=null;
        roll.setEnabled(true);
        checkWin(getFruits());
        slotOneFinished=false;
        slotTwoFinished=false;
        slotThreeFinished=false;
    }
}
```

**Start function**

```
 public void start() {
        if(executor==null) {
            count =0;
            executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,10,200,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }
```

**Animate function**

```
  public void animate(final int maxCount, final ImageSwitcher slot, int i) {
    if (i<maxCount){
        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.new_slot_item_in);
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.old_item_out);
        slot.setInAnimation(in);
        slot.setOutAnimation(out);
        int fruit = randomFruit();
        slot.setTag(fruit);
        slot.setImageResource(fruit);
    }else {
        stop(slot);
    }
}
```

Count is set to 0 at the beginning of the program and randomSwitchCount() returns a random number between 10 and 40. I am assuming that I do not have the correct order of running some code. I used the toast messages to highlight my problem during testing. If there is anything else which you see wrong with my functions & logic, I am all ears.

Thanks,

Pi Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timer was scheduled to run one more time. But isFinished was set to false for every slot just before the timer ran so the condition became true. Instead, I set them to false only when the roll button was finished so that the time was in sync with the win detection.